# Ubuntu 17.10 won't start on QEMU

Tags: boot, virtualization, 17.10, qemu

I tried several times to install a new image of Ubuntu 17.10 on Qemu. Everytime I install and reboot, it starts for the first time Then I apply the updates, and reboot again. It gets stuck in the Ubuntu (loading) screen. Won't boot and CPU usage gets very low. Ubuntu 16.04 won't do this.

The problem is only with the QXL monitor. If I change it to VGA, VMVGA, etc, all them work

Comment: did you install `spice-vdagent` together with your updates? If yes try this without the use of this, I found that installing the agent, somehow bugs up all installation attempts of 17.10.

Comment: how do I remove it from the updates?

Comment: It should not be installed by updates, you have to do the installation by hand. an other cause of the 17.10 installation on Qemu I found was changing the resolution form the default to something else, but no clue why it behaves like this. Another thing might be you want to switch to VirtIO for the display driver.

Comment: @Videonauth yes, I restarted without changing the resolution and the problem did not happen again. So I think there's no solution to run 17.10

Comment: Well I run it simply unaltered which works for my purposes. No clue yet how to make it work with resolution change and vdagent yet tho

Comment: qemu or KVM ? What settings are you using to boot ?

Comment: @Panther KVM, x_86_64, BIOS, chipset i440FX

Comment: settings ? what graphics?

Comment: @Panther display: spice server. I don't know much, I'm using virt-manager. What am I supposed to look at?

Comment: Looks like a bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spice-vdagent/+bug/1734253 . You can try connecting with spice-client or using an alternate graphics setting. `remote-viewer spice://myhost:3001` see https://www.spice-space.org/docs/manual/

Comment: @Panther nice you  found my bugreport ;). GuerlandoOCs you should mark this as affecting you so it gets confirmed and triaged.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs please try the following after making a snapshot of your VM, boot into it and `sudo apt install qemu-guest-agent` when done with the installation set your screenresolution and reboot. Tell me please if this works for you. Then i can write an answer.

Comment: FWIW - Ubuntu 17.10 works fine here, Centos host mind you . Nothing other than an standard install, spice server, fully updated. If it is host dependent perhaps this information will help in your but reprot.